# Sorting on a protected Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

i have an excel related problem. I already searched older questions but neither of them have a good anwser for the problem.

I want to be able to sort, filter and use pivot tables on a protected sheet. I researched so far that one can not sort on a protected sheet. But is there a way to unlock the sheet for sorting and then lock it again after successful sorting?

thx in adavance

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can choose things to allow when you protect a sheet, such as filtering (when you click on "Protect Sheet", there is a list titled "Allow all users of this worksheet to:").

With sorting, it really depends on whether the cells in the table are locked or not. If not, it works just by allowing it in the protection menu. If some are locked, there is a workaround with

> Review (Ribbon) > Allow users to edit ranges

whilst disallowing selection of locked cells. Here you basically add the locked ranges of your table to the "editable" ranges, but at the same time you disallow users to click on them, so that they stay in fact uneditable. But this method does come with its drawbacks, I'm sure you can find more details on google.

About pivot tables, try checking the option "Use pivot table reports" in the list when locking the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to right click on the filter cells > Format cells > Protection tab > untick 'Locked'. Then protect the worksheet tick the options to 'Sort', 'Use Autofilter', 'Use PivotTable reports'. This will allow the user to sort, filter etc but will also allow them to edit the cells directly i.e. not just using the sort button. You could untick the 'Select locked cells' option when you protect the worksheet to prevent this direct editing.

Comment: No when the cells are locked, what you say would not allow the user to edit a locked cell directly. However, sorting such a table that contains locked cells would also not be possible.